# How to convert CLOB to VARCHAR2 inside oracle pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, clob

I have a clob variable, need to assign it to varchar2 variable. The data inside clob var is less than 4000 (i..e varchar2's maxsize) oracle10+

I tried

```
  report_len  := length(report_clob);
  report      := TO_CHAR(dbms_lob.substr(report_clob, report_len, 1 ));
  report_clob := null;
```

but it turns report into long value which I see while debugging. Also when I call this sql (proc) from my C# code. It complains saying buffer too small, because I send parameter as per varchar, but the above conversion might be turning it into long value.

I even tried direct assignment

```
   report_clob := report
```

getting the same result.

**EDIT**

Ok, to answer the questions below please see:
I debug using test script in PL/SQL developer. report variable is varchar2(4000). When I step after 2nd line. report shows to be a long value and it just says (Long Value) . cant even see the contents.

report and report_clob are out variable from the procedure. This procedure is called from C# code.

There is an exception string buffer too small in C# when I call this procedure. I have given 5000 as size of report variable in C# sufficient to receive 4000 max characters value from the procedure. So I guess problem doesn't lie there.

And when I assign report:= 'some string....' then C# call works fine.

So my investigation says that report := transform (report_clob) is making report become long value or some such thing (weird) which makes C# code problematic to handle larger value in 5000 varchar out parameter.

Any more detail I will be happy to provide.

Comment: How is `report` declared? `LONG` or `VARCHAR2`? How are you debugging, and how are you returning the value to `c#` - function return or output parameter, and what type is that?

Comment: `report := CAST(report_clob AS VARCHAR2(3999));`

Comment: `DBMS_LOB.substr` returns a VARCHAR2, you don't need the `TO_CHAR` function. Also what do you call a long value? How do you debug? What message error exactly are you getting (ie Oracle or C#)? How is the report variable declared?

Comment: pls see update in my question EDIT area

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my VARCHAR2 being converted to a LONG in my PL/SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838274/why-is-my-varchar2-being-converted-to-a-long-in-my-pl-sql)

Comment: @jonearles How does that corroborate to the fact that the C# code is/was throwing "String buffer" error?

Answer (score 24):

Quote (read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions016.htm))-

> When you use CAST to convert a CLOB value into a character datatype
> or a BLOB value into the RAW datatype, the database implicitly
> converts the LOB value to character or raw data and then explicitly
> casts the resulting value into the target datatype.

So, something like this should work-

```
report := CAST(report_clob AS VARCHAR2(100));
```

Or better yet use it as `CAST(report_clob AS VARCHAR2(100))` where ever you are trying to use the `BLOB` as `VARCHAR`.

Comment: When using `CAST(...)` in a select, you need to specify size e.g. `VARCHAR2(20)`

Comment: Exactly, @Wassadamo. I struggled with it for quite a while before realizing.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for cases when CLOB data is large - I got the exception ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR... I ended up truncating the CLOB to 4000 characters or less, and then converting the truncated result to varchar - by using the function from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12778244/19032206

Answer (score 4):

**Converting VARCHAR2 to CLOB**

In PL/SQL a CLOB can be converted to a VARCHAR2 with a simple assignment, SUBSTR, and other methods.  A simple assignment will only work if the CLOB is less then or equal to the size of the VARCHAR2.  The limit is 32767 in PL/SQL and 4000 in SQL (although 12c allows 32767 in SQL).

For example, this code converts a small CLOB through a simple assignment and then coverts the beginning of a larger CLOB.

```
declare
    v_small_clob clob := lpad('0', 1000, '0');
    v_large_clob clob := lpad('0', 32767, '0') || lpad('0', 32767, '0');
    v_varchar2   varchar2(32767);
begin
    v_varchar2 := v_small_clob;
    v_varchar2 := substr(v_large_clob, 1, 32767);
end;
```

**LONG?**

The above code does not convert the value to a LONG.  It merely looks that way because of limitations with PL/SQL debuggers and strings over 999 characters long.

For example, in PL/SQL Developer, open a Test window and add and debug the above code.  Right-click on `v_varchar2` and select "Add variable to Watches".  Step through the code and the value will be set to "(Long Value)".  There is a `...` next to the text but it does not display the contents.
[image: PLSQL Developer Long Value]

**C#?**

I suspect the real problem here is with C# but I don't know how enough about C# to debug the problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ADD (COLUMN_NAME_NEW varchar2(4000 char));
update TABLE_NAME set COLUMN_NAME_NEW = COLUMN_NAME;

ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME DROP COLUMN COLUMN_NAME;
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME rename column COLUMN_NAME_NEW to COLUMN_NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my aproximation:

```
  Declare 
  Variableclob Clob;
  Temp_Save Varchar2(32767); //whether it is greater than 4000

  Begin
  Select reportClob Into Temp_Save From Reporte Where Id=...;
  Variableclob:=To_Clob(Temp_Save);
  Dbms_Output.Put_Line(Variableclob);


  End;
```

Comment: there is a person who puts -1 to all.