# Why is my VARCHAR2 being converted to a LONG in my PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I am using PL/SQL Developer 9.0.6, working on an Oracle 11g database.

I have a procedure in a package that creates some dynamic SQL to be run with `execute immediate`.  The variable `vSQL` is declared as `varchar2(4000)`.  My procedure builds and runs `vSQL` correctly, and returns a `ref cursor` through an `out` paramter.

However, while debugging my procedure, something unexpected happened: I set a watch on `vSQL`, and when the length `vSQL` gets to 1000 or greater, the value in the Watch window changes from the *contents* of `vSQL` to the *literal* '(Long Value)' and I can no longer view the contents of `vSQL`.

Why does this happen?  Is there any way that I can cast `vSQL` so that I can still view it while debugging my procedure?

Comment: There's a difference between an Oracle `LONG` and the client displaying the text 'Long value'. There are some forum posts that suggest this is an 'Oracle debugger' problem - e.g. [here](http://forums.allroundautomations.com/ubb/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=13779&PHPSESSID=2e3c1b028a66500ae8a1730abc88b993), [here](http://forums.allroundautomations.com/ubb/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=27694&PHPSESSID=2e3c1b028a66500ae8a1730abc88b993) and [here](http://forums.allroundautomations.com/ubb/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=23444&PHPSESSID=2e3c1b028a66500ae8a1730abc88b993).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, PL/SQL Developer cannot display 4000 characters in the debugger.  This is probably a limitation of the Oracle package DBMS_DEBUG.

As a workaround, you can use Oracle SQL Developer, which uses a different debugger, DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.  In general, PL/SQL Developer is a thousand times better than Oracle SQL Developer.  But if you need to debug large strings or collections then Oracle SQL Developer works better.

Answer (score 1):

For debugging purpose you can have array of varchar2 having length of 1000 each element and max to 4 elements in it so it will overcome problem of exceeding 1000 char limit for debuging and still you can monitor the varchar2(4000)'s value